# Method setFont() not applicable for arguments [JLabel] (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, arguments

This is the code below and I am getting error because of setfont() function applied on JLabel. The syntax of `setFont()` seems to be correct.

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class Font  {
    public static void main(String Args[])
    {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        JLabel string1=new JLabel("Some Text");
        string1.setBounds(100,100,450,300);
        JTextField txt=new JTextField("add");
        string1.setFont (new Font("Arial", Font.Bold, 12));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(string1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


   }
 }
```

And the error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method setFont(java.awt.Font) in the type JComponent is not applicable for the arguments (Font)
    Bold cannot be resolved or is not a field

    at Font.main(Font.java:13)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program is calling your class with name Font.
Either change the name of your class or use new java.awt.Font instead of Font in above program like :

**Changing class name**

```
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Font1  {
public static void main(String Args[])
{
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    JLabel string1=new JLabel("Some Text");
    string1.setBounds(100,100,450,300);
    JTextField txt=new JTextField("add");
    string1.setFont (new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 22));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(string1);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

OR

**Without Class Name change**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Font  {
public static void main(String Args[])
{
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    JLabel string1=new JLabel("Some Text");
    string1.setBounds(100,100,450,300);
    JTextField txt=new JTextField("add");
    string1.setFont (new java.awt.Font("Arial", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 22));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(string1);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import the `java.awt.Font`. In your program your are create the instance of your Font.java class. The compiler complains that, you should provide the instance of `java.awt.Font` instead of your Font class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class Font  {
    public static void main(String Args[])
    {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        JLabel string1=new JLabel("Some Text");
        string1.setBounds(100,100,450,300);
        JTextField txt=new JTextField("add");
        string1.setFont (new java.awt.Font("Arial", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 12));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(string1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


   }
 }
```